# Bash script for archiving files from input parameters

Tags: bash, shell

I've been struggling for a while on a simple bash script that has to do the following things:

It has to take 2 parameters: the first one is the (nameofthefile).tar.gz and the second one is file that will be backed up. It will be compressed and archived. So it has to look probably like this when executed:

`./tar.sh messagesbackup /var/log/messages`

And the output will be:

`messagesbackup.tar.gz`

Also it has to throw an alert message if the user has not specified 2 parameters or one of the two (or the both) parameters are incorrect.

Comment: What have you tried on your own? And please elaborate what *incorrect* means here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this small script

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$2" ] && {
        echo "Usage: gz-name dir-to-backup"
        exit
}

GZNAME="$1.tar.gz"
DIRTOBK="$2"

tar -czvf "$GZNAME" "$DIRTOBK"
```

Comment: Anyway, why do you need a script that acts exactly like tar command?

Comment: Ah it will be used by people that are not so familiar with tar nor any shell commands, so I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Ah it will be used by people that are not so familiar with tar nor any shell commands, so I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Also I've modified your script a bit if you don't mind. Could you please check if it needs any optimizations?


```#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
        echo "No parameters specified!"
        exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f $DIRTOBK ]; then
        echo "File/directory does not exist!"
        exit 1
fi


GZNAME="$1.tar.gz"
DIRTOBK="$2"

tar -czf "$GZNAME" "$DIRTOBK"
exit 0
```

Comment: It looks ok but it's not easy to read it in this format. Try this tool https://www.shellcheck.net/